# Why does ints sometimes ask for double's print format in C?

Tags: c, floating-point, integer

I'm pretty sure some others are also confused with this one, because I am too.

While in the work of basing converting functions, I want to test out something first before I start making a function that converts an integer to a float or double.

So what I wrote in C99 is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int number = 200;
    printf("%f\n", number);
}
```

Of course, there would be an error if I tried to compile it, but it is not the error I expected:

```
make_float.c:5:20: error: format specifies type 'double' but the argument has type 'int' [-Werror,-Wformat]
    printf("%f\n", number);
            ~~     ^~~~~~
            %d
```

Now I'm confused, I thought `%f` is only for `float` and `double`, but `%d` handles `double` and also `int`. So I tried fixing the program with the suggestion, and what came out was just a number, and not a floating-point value, which confuses me:

```
~/BPML/C/Part3/Conversion/ $ make make_float
clang -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wshadow    make_float.c  -lcrypt -lcs50 -lm -o make_float
~/BPML/C/Part3/Conversion/ $ ./make_float
200
~/BPML/C/Part3/Conversion/ $
```

Q: Why does `printf` let `int` be printed out using `%d` if it stands for `double` or decimal?

Comment: "but %d handles double and" uhm... no, it doesn't. It is used to print `signed int` and anything that gets converted to that. Nothing else.

Comment: Which suggestion are you talking about? How did you "fix" it?

Comment: "Just because of the format" Which format? If you changed `%f` to `%d` then the expected output is an integer. `%d` is not related to `double`or `float` at all.

Comment: BTW: If that is "not the error I expected", which one did you expect?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222396/discussion-between-gerhardh-and-bpml).

Comment: You can compile a program where you give a `double` to `printf()` where `printf()` expects a `int`, but you get UB when you run the program.

Comment: %d stands for "decimal", not "double". %d expects you to pass an int, and it will be printed as a decimal number

Answer (score 3):

The error that you got is expected: The format `"%f"` **requires** a `double` argument. You pass an `int`, so your compiler correctly catches the error. The `f` stands for "Floating point", i.e. a number that may require a decimal point `.` in its printout. `double` is a floating point type.

Likewise, the format `"%d"` **requires** an `int` argument. You cannot pass a `double`. The `d` in the format string stands for "decimal", as opposed to `x` for "hexadecimal", `o` for "octal" or even `u` for unsigned. All these conversion require an `int` or `unsigned int` argument. The `"%d"` format outputs an integer in decimal format, and thus requires an `int` argument.

You cannot pass a floating point value in the place of an integer argument and vice versa. If `int` is a fish, `double` is a plant. They cannot be used interchangeably.

---

When you pass a smaller type than `int` or `double` as a `printf()` argument, the C language will implicitly convert the argument. `char` and `short` will be promoted to an `int`, while `float` will be promoted to a `double`. That is why you can use a `char` argument for the `"%d"` format, or a `float` argument for the `"%f"` format. After the promotion, each argument gets the type it requires.

Answer (score 0):

### What the C-Standard says:

A `"%d"` expects a `int`. From the C11 draft, 7.21.6.1 The `fprintf` function - 8 (which is the same for `printf()`):

> d,i    The `int` argument is converted to signed decimal ...

Providing the wrong type causes UB. From the C11 draft, 7.21.6.1 The `fprintf` function - 9 .

> 9 If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined.
> 275) If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding
> conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.

`printf()` uses the same format and rules as `fprintf()`. From the C11 draft, 7.21.6.3 The `printf` function - 2:

> 2 The printf function is equivalent to fprintf with the argument
> stdout interposed before the arguments to printf.

Note that there is a promotion, a `float` is promoted to `double`, so using a `float` when `printf()` expects a `double` is fine and therefore `"%f"` works for `double` and `float`. From the C11 draft, 6.5.2.2 Function calls - 6-7:

> 6 If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that
> does not include a prototype, the integer promotions are performed on
> each argument, and arguments that have type float are promoted to
> double. These are called the default argument promotions. ...

> 7 If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that
> does include a prototype, the arguments are implicitly converted, as
> if by assignment, to the types of the corresponding parameters, taking
> the type of each parameter to be the unqualified version of its
> declared type. The ellipsis notation in a function prototype
> declarator causes argument type conversion to stop after the last
> declared parameter. The default argument promotions are performed on
> trailing arguments.

### Why the same format specifier can not work for multiple different types

I explain how a calling convention on a CPU may work, to explain how `printf()` and `va_list` work, but this is not based on a real CPU. Lets say the calling convention pushes each argument on the stack. The first argument for a function call is put as last element on the stack. When you have a function call like `foo(arg0,arg1,arg2,arg3);`, the stack may look like this before calling the function:

```
 Address  Data
+-------+-------+ 
| 0x42  | arg0  |  <-- Stack pointer points here. 
+-------+-------+  
| 0x41  | arg1  |
+-------+-------+
| 0x40  | arg2  |
+-------+-------+
| 0x3F  | arg3  |
+-------+-------+
```

Lets say all arguments have type `int` and `sizeof(int)==1`, to make it simple. This is for a normal function call, but it is the same for a function call with a variable amount of arguments. Let use assume this is the prototype of `foo()`: `void foo(int arg0, ...)`.
The function `foo()` uses `va_start(ap,arg0)` somewhere, after that `ap` points to `arg0`. After that the stack can look like this

```
 Addres  Data
+-------+-------------+ 
| 0x44  | ap          |  <-- local variables of foo()
+-------+-------------+ 
| 0x43  | returnAdd   |  <-- caller address 
+-------+-------------+ 
| 0x42  | arg0        |  
+-------+-------------+  
| 0x41  | arg1        |  <-- ap points here
+-------+-------------+
| 0x40  | arg2        |
+-------+-------------+
| 0x3F  | arg3        |
+-------+-------------+
```

If `foo()` now uses `va_arg(ap,int)`, it will get the data at address 0x41 and interprets it as a `int`. And `ap` will now point to the next argument for the next use of `va_arg()`. The stack may look like this now:

```
 Addres  Data
+-------+-------------+ 
| 0x44  | ap          |  <-- local variables of foo()
+-------+-------------+ 
| 0x43  | returnAdd   |  <-- caller address 
+-------+-------------+ 
| 0x42  | arg0        |  
+-------+-------------+  
| 0x41  | arg1        | 
+-------+-------------+
| 0x40  | arg2        |  <-- ap points here
+-------+-------------+
| 0x3F  | arg3        |
+-------+-------------+
```

Lets assume we didn't call `foo()` and using a `int` but a `double` for `arg1`. According to C this does create UB and everything can happen. On our system the double is maybe stored at address 0x40-0x41. Then the CPU would just interpret half of this `double` as an `int` and it seems like a random value. The other values after that are also messed up since on our system `sizeof(double)!=sizeof(int)`. `va_list` has no way of knowing what types the arguments have, this is why the `va_arg()` macro needs a type as second argument.

On some systems the registers are used and some of them have different registers for integers and floating point numbers. There you get even more strange behavior. Since there is no way of knowing what types the caller provided, the format string has to be correct.

The format string is the only way `printf()` can know the types. If the format string is does not match the arguments, you get UB, For this reason. So you can not provide a `double` when you use the `"%d"` format specifier in `printf()`, since it expects a `int`. (The standard does not say `printf()` has to use a `va_list`, but i ignored that since it makes it is used in most implementations).